# Can MS Services for Unix be deployed and accessed from a shared drive?

Tags: windows, unix, services, compatibility

I'm interested in experimenting with replacing our dependency on MKS with [MS' Sevices for Unix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496506.aspx) toolset. I was wondering if anyone has any experience with deploying SFU on a shared drive? We like to, wherever possible, host our dev tools on one central NAS and call to the NAS to access the tools instead of rolling stuff out to each and every desktop.

I'm not interested in the NFS support or ActiveState Perl. Really, none of the daemon technology is required here. I'm looking for replacements for the coreutils/binutils stuff you find in Linux (and MKS on Windows): sed, awk, csh, bash, grep, ls, find -- the meat-and-potates command line apps that our build and test scripts are built around.

If I limit the install to just the Interix GNU Components (and maybe the Remote Connectivity components) will is run nicely from a shared location?

Edit: So the answer is, "No, you cannot". At least not easily. I get this:

[image]

To head off some questions:

- Yes, I've looked at Cygwin. Unfortunately it's performance in our build and test environment is poor. It runs considerably slower than MKS and it's not a direct drop-in replacement for MKS (thanks to its internal pathing and limitations with commands like 'ps'), so it's a tougher sell.
- Yes, I'm looking at the [MinGW offering](http://www.mingw.org/) in parallel to this.

Comment: @Ian C. - MS SFU is a subsystem that runs on top of the Windows kernel at the same level as the Win32 subsystem, which is likely why it needs a local install. I don't know if this will help, but take a look at the product Ch: http://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/shell/unixcommands.html, http://www.softintegration.com/docs/ch/shell/. It gives you many of the Unix utilities, and may work for you.

Comment: @Joe Internet - thanks. I'll look into that on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried it, but it should work.

I'd say just run a test. That's going to be the best way to find out.

Install it, map a drive/folder on your local machine to the location. Add that to your path. And just try using each on a set of files on your drive and on the NAS.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I'll roll it out this way, but with Windows installers I'm always worried about the local changes it's making: registry modifications, local DLLs being dumped in %SystemRoot%. Mostly interested in knowing if anyone has bumped up against nastiness like that.

Comment: @Ian it's a pretty light install, it does other stuff but most of the functionality you get just by adding those tools to your path

Comment: @Tyler: Oh well! I tried. :)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/870088/pictures/mssfu.jpg

Comment: @Ian, what about installing it locally, copying the files to the network share, uninstalling it. And then adjusting the path. It really seems like it *should* work.

Comment: @Tyler: I think I'm asking more of a toolkit that's dead at the end of month than I should be. I'm giving up on this one, but thanks for the help. SFU is no longer being offered after March of this year. Figure I should take MS' hint. :)

Comment: @Tyler - The applications couldn't run without the subsystem. See my comment above.

Comment: @Ian C. - Do you have a link for the SFU / March comment? FWIW, SFU has been renamed to Subsystem for Unix-based Applications for Vista/Server2008(r2)/Win7, and is now a feature that can be enabled via Control Panel. It may be that SFU is being EOLed because its' targeted platform is XP/Server2003r1 (it's included in Server2003r2), which you know have been EOLed. If you want to keep at it, take a look at the SUA Community website & forums: http://www.interopsystems.com/community/.